# Is there a alternative to get .NET that doesn't need admin password?

Tags: c#, .net

I use my school laptop that is controlled by my city so im unable to use anything that requires admin rights since no one in my school has the password. A way to get .NET without admin would be preferable.
i program in C#

Comment: https://repl.it/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/). That's a package manager for Windows and may be interesting in your case. As mentioned:

> Scoop installs programs to your home directory by default. So you don’t need admin permissions to install programs (...)

The installation is pretty easy and well detailed on the website:

```
iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex
```

(If you encounter an error, run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser` in your PowerShell)

Once the installation is done, you can install dotnet with it, since [it is in the main bucket](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/blob/master/bucket/dotnet-sdk.json):

```
scoop install dotnet-sdk
```